# Parsing a json file returns unwanted result

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

After a bit of struggling I finally got my Json file to parse. Although I guess it is parsing.. I am getting nil when Trying to access a value with alot of "objects". This is my code using the [swiftyJson](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) library. And here is how my [json](http://pastebin.com/7feuPU83) looks like. The code I am using is

```
import UIKit

class MapViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let jsonData = getJSON("hls", extn: "json") {
            println(jsonData)
            let jsonDataResult = JSON(jsonData)
            var js = jsonDataResult["name"].string
            println("\(js)")

        }
    }

    func getJSON(fileName: String, extn: String) -> NSData?
    {
        if let fileURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(fileName, withExtension: extn) {
            if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: fileURL) {
                return data
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

}
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong getting the following output in my console. Any help and tips would be appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using SwiftyJSON, I believe you need to use the other initializer.  That is to say:

```
let jsonDataResult = JSON(jsonData)
```

in order for that to work jsonData would already have been run through and parsed once before.  The init you are wanting is the following, because you are passing it raw nsData as seen in your output.

```
let jsonDataResult = JSON(data: jsonData)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is it :) Didn't know there was a difference between these two initializers.